# Настройка параметров плавающих обтекаемых объектов в LyX

Tags: lyx

Вот, когда я в LyX пытался вставить плавающий обтекаемый рисунок через **Вставка>Плавающий объект>Обтекаемый рисунок**, ну, туда еще, понятно, графику вставлял, у меня получалось следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
в результате чего, как читатель, вероятно, уже догадался, глядя на код, находящийся в окошечке *LaTeX Source*, (это окошечко появляется при нажатии левой кнопки мышки **Вид>View Source** (или *Вид>Просмотреть исходный код*, пункт меню с таким названием - это тот же пункт того же меню, названный мной перед этими скобками, только в зависимости от используемого файла локализации с расширением `.mo`, о котором я расскажу позже, этот пункт может называться по-разному), в создающемся файле `.pdf` соответствующий рисунок появляется аж на полстраницы. Может, кто-нибудь знает, как это можно изменить?

Answer (score 1):

Я довольно долго не мог найти способа этим управлять, пока не наткнулся [на этот маленький блог](http://obscurityway.blogspot.com/2011/01/lyx.html). Я еще раз здесь перескажу, что там пишется. Итак, после вставки через **Вставка>Плавающий объект>Обтекаемый рисунок** появляется красный прямоугольник с надписью *обтекаемый объект: Рисунок*. Вот по этой надписи и щелкаем правой кнопкой мышки. В появившемся выпадающем списке щелкаем левой кнопкой мышки пункт *Настройки...* :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В появившемся диалоговом окне и устанавливаем ширину рисунка и другие параметры так, как нам и нужно. Однако при использовании этого метода в создаваемом `.pdf` могут появляться не очень желательные места, к примеру, такого вида:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как ни странно это звучит, но в этом случае к счастью, приведенную выше ссылку с ответом на этот вопрос я нашел не сразу и, пока я ее искал, мне удалось найти альтернативный способ решения этой проблемы. Суть этого способа в том, что мы нужное мне фото вставляем через **Вставка>Изображение**, а по бокам от этого вставленного таким образом фото мы в предварительно вставленные коды ТеХ (`Ctrl`+`l`) вписываем то, что обычно вписываем в таких случаях в файл `.tex`, открытый в каком-нибудь редакторе LaTeX - например, TeXworks или TeXmаker (напомню, что LyX - это не редактор, а процессор) слева и справа от

```
\includegraphics{какой-нибудь графический файл}
```

, а именно: в левый от фото такой код мы вставляем

```
\begin{wrapfigure}
```

с последующими нужными нам опциями, повторюсь, точно такими же, какие мы пишем в подобных участках кода файла `.tex`. В коде справа от вставленного фото мы пишем

```
\end{wrapfigure}
```

В результате получается, например, так:
[image]
И вот этот вариант вставки плавающей обтекаемой графики представляется мне более гибким, чем способ, предусмотренный создателями программы: именно, если при вставке плавающей графики стандартным способом управлять появлением/не появлением

```
caption, protect
```

(см. часть окна программы LyX *LaTeX/Source* на первом фото настоящей страницы) не получается, то при таком способе мы получаем полный контроль над кодом, который при экспорте в какой-нибудь формат, перед появлением этого формата, будет записан в соответствующий файл `.tex`. И, как следствие этого, у нас появляется возможность предотвращать появление показанных выше нежелательных мест в `.pdf`. Именно, если в `.pdf` где-нибудь появилось такое место с фото, то в месте файла `.lyx`, создающем это нежелательное место, в блок кода TeX, содержащий

```
\end{wrapfigure}
```

, мы перед этим окончанием окружения вставляем

```
\vspace{- какая-то длина, в см, в мм}
```

Не могу утверждать точно, что нужно указывать отрицательную длину какого-нибудь фиксированного значения, но я во всех случаях, когда мне это становилось необходимым до сих пор, писал

```
\vspace{-2.5cm}
```

И всегда использование этого значения вертикального пробела приводила к исчезновению таких дефектов в `.pdf`. Однако, при таком способе вставки плавающей обтекаемой графики становится необходимым подключение пакета *wrapfig* в **Документ>Настройки>Преамбула LaTeX**. Отмечу еще, что в LyX вообще, независимо от способа вставки плавающей обтекаемой графики, если при классе документа, в названии которого есть AMS, используются поля в **Документ>Настройки>Поля страницы** не по умолчанию, плавающие обтекаемые рисунки в получающемся `.pdf` уходят далеко вправо.