# Самостоятельное добавление кнопки в меню

Tags: lyx

Как добавить самостоятельно кнопку в меню или на панель задач в программе LyX ?

Answer (score 0):

Докладываю. Сначала я покажу, как добавить какую-нибудь кнопку в какое-нибудь меню. Для примера, я покажу, как добавить в меню **Правка** кнопку, при нажатии на которую будет начинаться математический режим, туда будет вводиться формула

[image]

и после этого курсор 2 раза перемещается влево, так, что после окончания выполнения этой команды курсор начинает мигать слева от только что введенной формулы. При этом я хочу, чтобы эта кнопка стояла между кнопками **Вставить** и **Вставить недавнее**, сверху этой кнопки помещалась полоса, такая, как, ну, знаете, есть же в меню полосы, разделяющие их на блоки, в которых группируются как-то связанные друг с другом кнопки. А отображаемое имя этой кнопки должно быть *drob' s chislitelem*. Для того, чтобы выполнить эту задачу - частный случай задач, заявленных в названии этой темы, нам потребуется редактировать файлы, находящиеся в папке `C:\Program Files\LyX 2.0\Resources\ui`. Именно, для того, чтобы изменить какое-нибудь меню, нам нужно редактировать файл *stdmenus.inc*, находящийся в этой папке. Открываем его в каком-нибудь редакторе, я это все делаю в банальном Блокноте. Где интуитивно, где глядя на код и, держа в уме горячие клавиши, которыми я пользовался в LyX, когда я еще только-только начал изучение этой программы и о создании собственных горячих клавиш не могло быть и речи, я понял, что редактировать нужно блок кода этого файла, начинающийся с

```
#
#EDIT MENU
#
Menu "edit"
```

А именно: после строки

```
ltem "Paste" "paste"
```

добавить 2 строки

```
Separator
Item "drob' s chislstelem" "command-sequence math-mode; math-insert \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}; char-left; char-left;"
```

Первая из добавленных строк как раз и дает разделяющую полоску, описанную выше. Сохраняем изменения в stdmenus.inc, перезапускиваем) LyX. В результате получаем вот что:

[image]

Так, теперь займемся добавлением кнопок на панели задач. Признаюсь, что, как добавлять кнопки на панели задач, я подсмотрел [вот здесь](http://www.thousandmonkeys.com/category/lyx/). А процедура добавления кнопок в меню, описанная выше была додумана уже мной на базе этого узнанного материала. И, уж, конечно, я не претендую ни на какое авторство. Ну, и вот... Вероятно, внимательный читатель [вот в этом посте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1063868/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-lyx) уже заметил отличие панели инструментов в окне прогры LyX, которой пользуюсь я (она, эта отличающаяся панель, расположена на фото там точно над рабочей областью, в которой я пишу) от аналогичной панели инструментов в еще неизмененной прогре LyX. Именно, отличие этой панели сразу бросается в глаза большущей кнопкой, на которой имеется лишь частично вошедшая на фото надпись *Moyacom [Ctrl + 0 1]*. Однако, той кнопкой я не ограничился, потому что не ясно было, как на кнопки, созданные пользователем, прикреплять еще и какие хочешь картинки. Поэтому я создал еще одну кнопку. На следующем фото созданные мной на одной панели инструментов кнопки указаны красными стрелками:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот для начала я и расскажу, как создать кнопку, покрытую желаемой картинкой (у картинки **должно быть обязательно** расширение *.png*), при нажатии на которую выполняется команда, определенная в `C:\Users\ИВАН\AppData\Roaming\LyX2.0\commands\default.def`. Итак, вписываем в этот файл с новой строки следующее:

```
\define "pina2" "command-sequence math-mode; math-insert \dfrac<span>{</span>\pi<span>}</span><span>{</span>2<span>}</span>; char- right; char-right;"
```

Закрываем файл default.def, сохраняем изменения. Далее, в папку `C:\Users\ИВАН\AppData\Roaming\LyX2.0\images\commands` копируем фото (повторюсь, **обязательно** расширения *.png*), под которым мы хотим, чтобы создаваемая нами кнопка появилась в окне прогры LyX, переименовываем это фото в *pina2*. Давайте договоримся, что кнопку мы добавляем на панель *Дополнительно* (на приведенном выше фото приведена измененная панель инструментов *Дополнительно*). Но сама програ LyX не знает панели инструментов с таким названием. Эта панель в понимании LyX называется *Extra* (я это выяснил, смотря на сообщения в не раз упоминавшейся в моих рассказах на этом форуме про прогру LyX области ее окна *Сообщения прогресса/отладки* при активации/деактивации этой панели через **Вид>Панели инструментов**). Отлично. Идем в уже упомянутую выше папку `C:\Program Files\LyX 2.0\Resources\ui`. Открываем файл *stdtoolbars.inc*, ищем там что-то, начинающееся со слова *extra* (возможно, с большой буквы) или что-то, похожее на, там, заголовок или что-то в этом духе, содержащее это слово. Чтобы не лезть далеко, мы добавим нашу кнопку в самое начало этой команды. Именно, вот участок кода того файла до моего вмешательства:

```
...................................................................
StickyPopupMenu "update-others" "Update other formats"
End

Toolbar "extra" "Extra"
Item "Default" "layout"
Item "Numbered list" "layout Enumerate"
...................................................................
```

А вот каким я сделал тот участок кода:

```
...................................................................
StickyPopupMenu update-others Update other formats
End

Toolbar "extra" "Extra"
Item "Privet moim chitatelyam" "call pina2"
Item "Default" "layout"
Item "Numbered list" "layout Enumerate"
...................................................................
```

, где многоточия - это строки файла stdtoolbars.inc, стоящие до и после приведенного кода этого файла. В принципе, все, закрываем с сохранением файл *stdtoolbars.inc*. Тогда после перезапуска LyX при активации панели *Дополнительно* на этой панели появляется новая функционирующая кнопка с тем изображением, которое мы и назначили и выполняющая ту функцию, которую мы и определили. Как видно из последнего фото, всплывающая подсказка определяется написанным нами в первой паре кавычек, относящихся к соответствующему *item*. В заключении скажу, что добавленная мной вторая кнопка была определена без участия файла default.def и, как я сказал выше, без умысла назначить на нее картинку, под которой эта кнопка отображалась бы в окне прогры LyX: я просто вставил перед последней строкой блока кода, в котором я делал только что описанные манипуляции, пустую строку и вставил в эту пустую строку следующий код:

```
item "Moyacom" "command-sequence math-mode; math-insert \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}; char-left; char-left;"
```

Comment: А где в названии темы про панель инструментов? Без этого с таким же успехом можно спросить: а почему это я, ни с того, ни с с сего приплел добавление кнопки еще и на панель инструментов? А где в названии темы упоминание названия программы, в которой это все происходит? Как человек поиском в гугле найдет это сообщение, если в его названии НЕТ ключевых слов, по которым, скорее всего, будет производиться поиск? Вы что учудили-то? Жесть. Айм шок.

Comment: Еще и репу сняли. Ну, ваще.